# Sonar reports different line and branch coverage than Idea, Eclipse, Maven and Jenkins

Tags: java, sonarqube, jacoco, sonarqube5.1, sonar-maven-plugin

I have all those tools reporting the same coverage with JaCoCo: 69% line coverage and 23% branch coverage.

*Note: Screenshots had been taken over several days so they have slightly different values, but the variance is < 1%*

Jenkins:
[image: jenkins]

Maven:
[image: maven]

Eclipse:
[image: eclipse]

However Sonar reports different values:

[image: sonar]

Maven project is structured as follows:

- main (aggregator)

  - java module
  - js (node) module

You can see the same coverage reported on main and java modules, and no coverage for the js one.

[image: Modules]

I'm using the latest versions of `jacoco`, `jacoco-maven-plugin` and Sonar's `Java Plugin`.

Here are the relevant build log fragments from `mvn sonar:sonar` -- all seem to be in order:

```
$ egrep -i 'jacoco|\[warn]' consoleText
[WARN] [04:34:29.569] 'sonar.dynamicAnalysis' is deprecated since version 4.3 and should no longer be used.
[WARN] [04:34:29.576] 'sonar.dynamicAnalysis' is deprecated since version 4.3 and should no longer be used.
[WARN] [04:34:29.593] 'sonar.dynamicAnalysis' is deprecated since version 4.3 and should no longer be used.
[INFO] [04:34:32.704] JaCoCoItSensor: JaCoCo IT report not found: /home/acme/workspace/example-Sonar-DSL/modules/example-main/target/jacoco-it.exec
[WARN] [04:34:32.952] Bytecode of dependencies was not provided for analysis of test files, you might end up with less precise results. Bytecode can be provided using sonar.java.test.libraries property
[WARN] [04:34:50.101] Cobertura report not found at /home/acme/workspace/example-Sonar-DSL/modules/example-main/target/site/cobertura/coverage.xml
[INFO] [04:35:03.391] Sensor JaCoCoSensor
[INFO] [04:35:03.406] Analysing /home/acme/workspace/example-Sonar-DSL/modules/example-main/target/jacoco.exec
[INFO] [04:35:03.712] Sensor JaCoCoSensor (done) | time=321ms
[INFO] [04:35:03.712] Sensor JaCoCoOverallSensor
[INFO] [04:35:03.714] Analysing /home/acme/workspace/example-Sonar-DSL/modules/example-main/target/jacoco.exec
[INFO] [04:35:03.762] Analysing /home/acme/workspace/example-Sonar-DSL/modules/example-main/target/sonar/jacoco-overall.exec
[INFO] [04:35:03.906] Sensor JaCoCoOverallSensor (done) | time=194ms
[INFO] [04:35:11.013] JaCoCoSensor: JaCoCo report not found : /home/acme/workspace/example-Sonar-DSL/modules/frontend/target/jacoco.exec
[INFO] [04:35:11.013] JaCoCoItSensor: JaCoCo IT report not found: /home/acme/workspace/example-Sonar-DSL/modules/frontend/target/jacoco-it.exec
[INFO] [04:35:11.179] JaCoCoSensor: JaCoCo report not found : /home/acme/workspace/example-Sonar-DSL/target/jacoco.exec
[INFO] [04:35:11.179] JaCoCoItSensor: JaCoCo IT report not found: /home/acme/workspace/example-Sonar-DSL/target/jacoco-it.exec
```

**Is this a bug in Sonar's Java Plugin?** 
I think it's highly unlikely that metric reported by sonar is correct when 3 other tools configured by different people consistently show different values.

Comment: Does this concern a multi module project ? if yes, do you have tests in some modules covering code in other modules ?

Comment: I second benzonico... I have come across projects that has test case for all modules in 1 module. In this case most tests throws error and coverage will b reported for 1 module that has test cases in it

Comment: No, it is a multi module project, but it has one only one java module and another one for fronted, so all JUnit tests are in the same module as code under test.

Comment: How are you running the analysis : with `mvn sonar:sonar` or with the sonar-runner ?

Comment: I run with `mvn sonar:sonar`

Comment: Do you have any coverage set for the javascript module ? is the different coverage reported at the root of your project ?

Comment: @benzonico no, there is no coverage for JS module -- root module reports the same values as the java one (please  see the added screenshot above)

Comment: Here is how is computing the "Unit Tests Coverage" measure : NUMBER_OF_LINES = number of lines + number of conditions. COVERED_LINES = NUMBER_OF_LINES - (number of uncovered lines + number of uncovered conditions. COVERAGE = (100 * COVERED_LINES) / NUMBER_OF_LINES.

Comment: have you checked which classes are part of the analysis, the numbers should match with jenkins/maven report. Further, how do you measure coverage in jenkins/maven, do you also use jacoco or another framework?

Comment: @GeraldMücke I use JaCoCo everywhere. Also you can see above that the number of classes for Maven and Jenkins report is the same. I'm not sure how would I check the number of classes considered by the coverage sensor in Sonar though

Comment: Sonar 5.3 has a coverage page showing the metrics used to calculate the coverage, but obviously you're on an earlier version. The Size-Metrics widget on the dashboard could be an indicator, but it doesn't consider files excluded from the coverage calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the coverage metric has fixed itself. It now reports correct values -- incidentally we've upgraded JDK to latest patch version (8u92) the same day.

This suggests the JaCoCo sensor works wrong depending on JRE, but needs more investigation.

[image: coverage trend]

Answer (score 2):

Here is how is computing the "Unit Tests Coverage" measure :

- NUMBER_OF_LINES = number of lines + number of conditions.
- COVERED_LINES = NUMBER_OF_LINES - (number of uncovered lines + number of uncovered conditions.

COVERAGE = (100 * COVERED_LINES) / NUMBER_OF_LINES.

Comment: I fail to see how is this relevant to my problem of **line** and **branch** coverage not matching the other reports?

Comment: It helps you to understand how the coverage is computed in SonarQube. The other reports are using a different way to compute this measure, that's why you have different result.

Comment: Are you saying the "line" and "condition" coverage reported in Sonar is not the same as "line" and "branch" coverage in other JaCoCo reports?

Comment: Indeed, the way the aggregation is done is probably not the same

Comment: According to http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Metric+Definitions#MetricDefinitions-Tests  line and branch coverage should be the same as reported by Maven or Jenkins plugin