# Code Coverage - Inconsistency between Jacaco and Sonar 7.0

Tags: maven, reflection, junit, sonarqube, jacoco

I have a Utility class, which consists of certain Strings and a private constructor. Using Reflections I have tested that constructor as well and these strings are used in turn in other classes for which tests are there. Jacoco shows full code coverage. When I run it in Sonar, the coverage shows these constructors and Strings are not covered. Why is it so? Sonar picks up the Jacoco reports for showing up coverage( If I am right). Then why is this inconsistency. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Check the versions of jacoco and sonar-java plugin and have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49879009/what-is-the-difference-between-jacoco-branch-coverage-and-sonar-condition-covera/49903432#49903432

Comment: Sonar Java version is 5.2.0.13398 and uses Jacoco 0.8.1 and Jacoco version I am using is also 0.8.1. Still shows a different coverage

Comment: @GeraldMücke still I am facing the issue, any idea  what's the fix, versions look similar

Comment: not really, maybe you could try the community forum to get any help